# angularFire not binding to objects

Tags: angularfire

I'm trying to write to an object in firebase, here is how i did it:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://ootest1.firebaseio.com/users/' + '-J6kDooooooz_eV3Cq' /*JobsManager.getCurrentUser().username*/);
angularFire(myDataRef, $scope, 'newUser');

if (!$scope.newUser.jobs)
    $scope.newUser.jobs = [];
```

The problem is that $scope.newUser is undefined.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The `angularFire` binding returns a promise, and the `$scope.newUser` model won't be defined until that promise is fulfilled:

```
var promise = angularFire(myDataRef, $scope, 'newUser');
// $scope.newUser is undefined
promise.then(function(){
  // $scope.newUser is defined
}
```